# How to work with slackbot in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api, chatbot

I am trying to build a slackbot for my group , I tried sample codes and some other things but its not sending message to the group.

first i tried via terminal

```
export SLACK_API_TOKEN="my_token_id"
```

Then

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
  "chat.postMessage",
  channel="#random",
  text="Hello from Python! :tada:",
  thread_ts="283.5127(dummy_id)",
  reply_broadcast=False
)

print(sc)

#<slackclient.client.SlackClient object at 0x109b77ba8>
```

But there is no message in slack group.

I tried with this code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
import os
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_API_TOKEN']
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)
print(sc.api_call("channels.list"))
```

its retuning :

```
{'error': 'invalid_auth', 'ok': False}
```

I am not getting what i am doing wrong , Access token is correct , i want to post some messages via a bot , so how i can create a bot on slack and using that bot i can send messages via python ?

Comment: If the error is `invalid_auth`, your access token is probably wrong even though you think it's correct.

Comment: @Tvde1 i regenerate the access token and tried but same error.

Comment: Is your environment variable correct? Try `print`ing it.

Comment: yup , its returning key something like '7S4z5lMQ'

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when I implemented a slack bot with php & symfony.
It's not that simple to create and configure the slack app, bot and OAuth permissions properly.

I explained all these configurations in this blog post if you need it: https://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/en/replace-erp-by-slack-bot-with-dialogflow-and-symfony/

Also my code in PHP is very similar to what you need to parse Slack requests and post to its API.

Summary, TL;DR:

- Go to https://api.slack.com/apps and click on 'Create New App'.
- In this app configuration, go to the left menu 'Bot Users' or from 'Basic Information' > 'Add features and functionality' > 'Bots'.
- Still in this app config, go to the menu 'OAuth & Permissions' and allow the scope 'chat:write:bot' and copy the value of 'OAuth Access Token'
- From your code, call 'chat.postMessage' API method with an 'Authorization' header using previous token value.

Comment: Please could you summarise the contents of the linked post here, in case it becomes unavailable in the future? Link-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

built this from some examples found on the web: [liza daly - brobot : github.com](https://github.com/lizadaly/brobot)
and 
[How to Build Your First Slack Bot with Python : fullstackpython.com](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/build-first-slack-bot-python.html)

certainly not the best implementation but it functions as an appropriate answer to (i think)

```
import random
import time
import re
from slackclient import SlackClient
bot_id = None
slack_token = 'xoxb-no.more.mister.nice.gui'
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

# constants

RTM_READ_DELAY = 1 # 1 second delay between reading from RTM
DEFAULT_RESPONSE = "greetings: 'hello', 'hi', 'greetings', 'sup', 'what's     up' / commands: 'do'"
DEFAULT_COMMAND = "do"
MENTION_REGEX = "^<@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"

def parse_bot_commands(slack_events):
    """
    parses a list of events coming from the slack rtm api to find bot commands
    :param slack_events:
    :return:
"""
for event in slack_events:
    if event["type"] == "message" and not "subtype" in event:
        user_id, message = parse_direct_mention(event["text"])
        if user_id == bot_id:
            return message, event["channel"]
return None, None
def parse_direct_mention(message_text):
"""
finds direct message and returns user id
:param message_text:
:return:
"""
matches = re.search(MENTION_REGEX, message_text)
# the first group contains the user name, the second group contains
# the remaining message

return (matches.group(1), matches.group(2).strip()) if matches else (None, None)
def handle_command(command, channel):
"""
    executes bot command if the command is known
:param command:
:param channel:
:return:
"""
GREETING_KEYWORDS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up",)
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["'sup brah", "hey", "*headnod*", "didjageddathingahsencha?"]

# default response is help text for the user
default_response = "Not sure what you mean. Try *{}*.".format(DEFAULT_RESPONSE)

# finds and executes the given command, filling the response
response = None

#implement more commands below this line
if command in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
    response = random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
else:
    if command.startswith(DEFAULT_COMMAND):
        response = "Sure...write some more code and I'll do that"

# Sends the response back to the channel
sc.api_call(
    "chat.postMessage",
    channel="#the_danger_room",
    as_user="true:",
    text=response or default_response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
if sc.rtm_connect(with_team_state=False):
    print("Connected and running!")

    #call web api method auth.test to get bot usre id
    bot_id = sc.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
    while True:
        command, channel = parse_bot_commands(sc.rtm_read())
        if command:
            handle_command(command, channel)
        time.sleep(RTM_READ_DELAY)
    else:
        print("Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.")
```